# trouble with multiple MySQL joins

Tags: mysql, join, inner-join

Okay, having some trouble; any assistance would be hugely appreciated.

So, both of my inner join statements work in the query when executed in separate attempts, but I really need both statements to work, as I am calling data from two different tables besides the main one I'm gathering data from.

```
SELECT
  `conferences_form_records`.`id`,
  `conferences`.`conf_name`,
  `events`.`event`

FROM `conferences_form_records`

inner join `conferences`
  on `conferences_form_records`.`conference`
  where `conferences_form_records`.`conference`=`conferences`.`id`

inner join `events`
  on `conferences_form_records`.`relay`
  where `conferences_form_records`.`relay`=`events`.`id`
```

I hope that's enough simplified provided info.

Comment: You don't add a `where` on each join - you do one big one at the end.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this... see if it gets you closer to where you want to be...

```
SELECT cfr.id
     , c.conf_name
     , e.event
  FROM conferences_form_records cfr
  JOIN conferences c
    ON c.id = cfr.conference
  JOIN events e
    ON e.id = cfr.relay;
```

Comment: Ooh 2900 - not that I'm counting :-)